# Disassemble a RAID 1 arragement without removing/reinstalling the system

Tags: raid

I've set up a Soft Raid 1 using Debians built in RAID systems. I set up the raid because I had a space HDD when I set up the server and thought why not. The RAID is set up using what-ever Debian did when I installed the OS (sorry, not a linux techie).

Now, how-ever I could really use the disk for a much more useful purpose.

Is it easy to discontinue the raid without having to reinstall the OS, and how would I go about doing this?

`fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000d9640

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048   976771071   488384512   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0009dd99

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048   950560767   475279360   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2       950562814   976771071    13104129    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sdb5       950562816   976771071    13104128   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdc: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x6fa10d6b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1              63  3907024064  1953512001    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdd: 7803 MB, 7803174912 bytes
122 heads, 58 sectors/track, 2153 cylinders, total 15240576 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1   *        8064    15240575     7616256    b  W95 FAT32
```

`fstab` content:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=cbc19adf-8ed0-4d20-a56e-13c1a74e9cf0 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=f6836768-e2b6-4ccf-9827-99f58999607e none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sda1       /media/usb0     auto    rw,user,noauto  0       0
/dev/sdc1       /media/mns       ntfs-3g defaults        0       2
```

Comment: The output from `fdisk` isn't consistent with your having a RAID1 volume. It's possible to have partitions with an incorrect type, but even then partition sizes don't match. Post the output of `cat /proc/mdstat`, `cat /proc/partitions`, `cat /proc/mounts`, `vgs` and `cat /sys/block/dm-*/dm/name` (I think that should let us conclusively determine what all your disks are being used for).

Comment: And also, please, post output of `lsblk` - it will print a good representation of your block devices layout including device-mapper ones.
And also tell us which devices you think could be united in RAID and what mountpoint (you think) RAID partition is mounted to.

Answer (score 20):

The easiest method, that requires no changes to your setup whatsoever, is probably to reduce the RAID to a single disk. That leaves you the option to add a disk and thus re-use the RAID at a later time.

```
mdadm /dev/mdx --fail /dev/disky1
mdadm /dev/mdx --remove /dev/disky1
mdadm --grow /dev/mdx --raid-devices=1 --force
```

The result would look something like this:

```
mdx : active raid1 diskx1[3]
      62519296 blocks super 1.2 [1/1] [U]
```

Ta-daa a single disk "RAID1".

If you want to get rid of the RAID layer altogether, it would involve `mdadm --examine /dev/diskx1` (to find out the data offset), `mdadm --zero-superblock` (to get rid of the RAID metadata), and `parted` to move the partition by the data offset so it points to the filesystem, and then update bootloader and system configs to reflect the absence of RAID...

Comment: The thing is, i did not use this mdadm program to create the raid. Infact, I've just installed it, and it says there are no raids?

Comment: If you're not using `mdadm` Software RAID, you should be more specific in your question.

Comment: I did try, but the guy who edited it aparently removed that part, sorry hadn't noticed that. I'm using what-ever Debian did when I installed the OS.

Comment: Looking at the fdisk output you provided, there is only one partition marked fd.  So I do not think RAID 1 is set up and running on your system.

Answer (score 1):

Just fail and remove one of your drives:

```
mdadm /dev/md0 --fail /dev/sdb --remove /dev/sdb
```

After that change your `/etc/fstab` to use the drive left in RAID.

Reboot. And then destroy your RAID:

```
mdadm /dev/md0 --destroy
```

Have fun :)

Comment: I dont have any drives mounted as md0...
My fsdisk -l http://pastebin.com/uFYmShmT - All I know is that it is one of the 500 gb drives that I need to disconnect.

Comment: I only see /dev/sda being marked as RAID. Please answer questions under original post.