How can I remove raid from my system?
I want to remove raid from my system as I am low on storage and I want to recover the second disk.
How can I recover the second disk, I tried but to no avail, here is my current state :
root@miirabox ~ # cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md2 : active raid1 nvme1n1p3[1] nvme0n1p3[0]
      965467456 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 8/8 pages [32KB], 65536KB chunk

md0 : active raid1 nvme1n1p1[1] nvme0n1p1[0]
      33520640 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      
md1 : active raid1 nvme0n1p2[0](F) nvme1n1p2[1]
      1046528 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]
      
unused devices: <none>


root@miirabox ~ # sudo mdadm --detail --scan
ARRAY /dev/md/1 metadata=1.2 name=rescue:1 UUID=36e3a554:de955adc:98504c1a:836763fb
ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 name=rescue:0 UUID=b7eddc10:a40cc141:c349f876:39fa07d2
ARRAY /dev/md/2 metadata=1.2 name=rescue:2 UUID=2eafee34:c51da1e0:860a4552:580258eb

root@miirabox ~ # mdadm -E /dev/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : b7eddc10:a40cc141:c349f876:39fa07d2
           Name : rescue:0
  Creation Time : Sun Sep 10 16:52:20 2023
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 67041280 sectors (31.97 GiB 34.33 GB)
     Array Size : 33520640 KiB (31.97 GiB 34.33 GB)
    Data Offset : 67584 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=67432 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 5f8a86c6:80e71724:98ee2d01:8a295f5a

    Update Time : Thu Sep 19 19:31:55 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 136 sectors
       Checksum : f2954bfe - correct
         Events : 60


   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

root@miirabox ~ # mdadm -E /dev/nvme0n1p2
/dev/nvme0n1p2:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 36e3a554:de955adc:98504c1a:836763fb
           Name : rescue:1
  Creation Time : Sun Sep 10 16:52:20 2023
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 2093056 sectors (1022.00 MiB 1071.64 MB)
     Array Size : 1046528 KiB (1022.00 MiB 1071.64 MB)
    Data Offset : 4096 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=4016 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 8d8e044d:543e1869:9cd0c1ee:2b644e57

    Update Time : Thu Sep 19 19:07:25 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : 4ce9a898 - correct
         Events : 139


   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

root@miirabox ~ # mdadm -E /dev/nvme0n1p3
/dev/nvme0n1p3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 2eafee34:c51da1e0:860a4552:580258eb
           Name : rescue:2
  Creation Time : Sun Sep 10 16:52:20 2023
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 1930934960 sectors (920.74 GiB 988.64 GB)
     Array Size : 965467456 KiB (920.74 GiB 988.64 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1930934912 sectors (920.74 GiB 988.64 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=48 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 68758969:5218958f:9c991c6b:12bfdca1

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Thu Sep 19 19:32:42 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : 4a44ff36 - correct
         Events : 13984


   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

root@miirabox ~ # mdadm -E /dev/nvme1n1p1
/dev/nvme1n1p1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : b7eddc10:a40cc141:c349f876:39fa07d2
           Name : rescue:0
  Creation Time : Sun Sep 10 16:52:20 2023
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 67041280 sectors (31.97 GiB 34.33 GB)
     Array Size : 33520640 KiB (31.97 GiB 34.33 GB)
    Data Offset : 67584 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=67432 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 0dfdf4af:d88b2bf1:0764dcbd:1179639e

    Update Time : Thu Sep 19 19:33:07 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 136 sectors
       Checksum : a9ca2845 - correct
         Events : 60


   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
root@miirabox ~ # mdadm -E /dev/nvme1n1p2
/dev/nvme1n1p2:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 36e3a554:de955adc:98504c1a:836763fb
           Name : rescue:1
  Creation Time : Sun Sep 10 16:52:20 2023
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 2093056 sectors (1022.00 MiB 1071.64 MB)
     Array Size : 1046528 KiB (1022.00 MiB 1071.64 MB)
    Data Offset : 4096 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=4016 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 228202fa:0491e478:b0a0213b:0484d5e3

    Update Time : Thu Sep 19 19:24:14 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : e29be2bc - correct
         Events : 141


   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : .A ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
root@miirabox ~ # mdadm -E /dev/nvme1n1p3
/dev/nvme1n1p3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 2eafee34:c51da1e0:860a4552:580258eb
           Name : rescue:2
  Creation Time : Sun Sep 10 16:52:20 2023
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 1930934960 sectors (920.74 GiB 988.64 GB)
     Array Size : 965467456 KiB (920.74 GiB 988.64 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1930934912 sectors (920.74 GiB 988.64 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=48 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 431be888:cb298461:ba2a0000:4b5294fb

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Thu Sep 19 19:33:21 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : 2a2ddb09 - correct
         Events : 13984


   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

root@miirabox ~ # mdadm -D /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Sun Sep 10 16:52:20 2023
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 33520640 (31.97 GiB 34.33 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 33520640 (31.97 GiB 34.33 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Thu Sep 19 19:34:08 2024
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : rescue:0
              UUID : b7eddc10:a40cc141:c349f876:39fa07d2
            Events : 60

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0     259        1        0      active sync   /dev/nvme0n1p1
       1     259        5        1      active sync   /dev/nvme1n1p1

root@miirabox ~ # mdadm -D /dev/md1
/dev/md1:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Sun Sep 10 16:52:20 2023
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 1046528 (1022.00 MiB 1071.64 MB)
     Used Dev Size : 1046528 (1022.00 MiB 1071.64 MB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Thu Sep 19 19:24:14 2024
             State : clean, degraded 
    Active Devices : 1
   Working Devices : 1
    Failed Devices : 1
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : rescue:1
              UUID : 36e3a554:de955adc:98504c1a:836763fb
            Events : 141

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       -       0        0        0      removed
       1     259        6        1      active sync   /dev/nvme1n1p2

       0     259        2        -      faulty   /dev/nvme0n1p2

root@miirabox ~ # mdadm -D /dev/md2
/dev/md2:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Sun Sep 10 16:52:20 2023
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 965467456 (920.74 GiB 988.64 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 965467456 (920.74 GiB 988.64 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Thu Sep 19 19:34:46 2024
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : rescue:2
              UUID : 2eafee34:c51da1e0:860a4552:580258eb
            Events : 13984

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0     259        3        0      active sync   /dev/nvme0n1p3
       1     259        7        1      active sync   /dev/nvme1n1p3

root@miirabox ~ # lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
loop0         7:0    0     4K  1 loop  /snap/bare/5
loop2         7:2    0  74.3M  1 loop  /snap/core22/1586
loop3         7:3    0  40.4M  1 loop  
loop4         7:4    0 269.8M  1 loop  /snap/firefox/4793
loop5         7:5    0  74.3M  1 loop  /snap/core22/1612
loop6         7:6    0  91.7M  1 loop  /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop8         7:8    0  38.8M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/21759
loop9         7:9    0 271.2M  1 loop  /snap/firefox/4848
loop10        7:10   0 504.2M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-42-2204/172
loop12        7:12   0 505.1M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-42-2204/176
loop13        7:13   0  38.7M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/21465
nvme0n1     259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0    32G  0 part  
│ └─md0       9:0    0    32G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0     1G  0 part  
│ └─md1       9:1    0  1022M  0 raid1 
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 920.9G  0 part  
  └─md2       9:2    0 920.7G  0 raid1 /
nvme1n1     259:4    0 953.9G  0 disk  
├─nvme1n1p1 259:5    0    32G  0 part  
│ └─md0       9:0    0    32G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─nvme1n1p2 259:6    0     1G  0 part  
│ └─md1       9:1    0  1022M  0 raid1 
└─nvme1n1p3 259:7    0 920.9G  0 part  
  └─md2       9:2    0 920.7G  0 raid1 /

root@miirabox ~ # cat /etc/fstab 
proc /proc proc defaults 0 0
# /dev/md/0
UUID=e9dddf2b-f061-403e-a12f-d98915569492 none swap sw 0 0
# /dev/md/1
UUID=d32210de-6eb0-4459-85a7-6665294131ee /boot ext3 defaults 0 0
# /dev/md/2
UUID=7abe3389-fe7d-4024-a57e-e490f5e04880 / ext4 defaults 0 0

This is what I managed to do :
root@miirabox ~ #  df -h 
df: /run/user/1000/gvfs: Transport endpoint is not connected
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           6.3G  5.7M  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/md2        906G  860G     0 100% /
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/md1        989M  271M  667M  29% /boot
tmpfs           6.3G  132K  6.3G   1% /run/user/134
tmpfs            32G  648K   32G   1% /run/qemu
tmpfs           6.3G  244K  6.3G   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs           6.3G  116K  6.3G   1% /run/user/140

root@miirabox ~ # cat cat /proc/mdstat
cat: cat: No such file or directory
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md2 : active raid1 nvme1n1p3[1] nvme0n1p3[0]
      965467456 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 8/8 pages [32KB], 65536KB chunk

md0 : active raid1 nvme1n1p1[1] nvme0n1p1[0]
      33520640 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      
md1 : active raid1 nvme0n1p2[0] nvme1n1p2[1]
      1046528 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

root@miirabox ~ # umount /dev/md1
root@miirabox ~ # umount /dev/md2
root@miirabox ~ # umount /dev/md0
umount: /dev/md0: not mounted.

root@miirabox ~ # mdadm --fail /dev/md1 /dev/nvme0n1p2
mdadm: set /dev/nvme0n1p2 faulty in /dev/md1
root@miirabox ~ # mdadm --remove /dev/md1

root@miirabox ~ # mdadm --fail /dev/md1 /dev/nvme1n1p2
mdadm: set device faulty failed for /dev/nvme1n1p2:  Device or resource busy
root@miirabox ~ # sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md1
mdadm: Cannot get exclusive access to /dev/md1:Perhaps a running process, mounted filesystem or active volume group?

root@miirabox ~ # sudo vgdisplay
root@miirabox ~ # lvdisplay

I was following a guide and could not proceed.
Please do not hesitate if you want more details. Thanks in advance.
EDIT : I apologise I was not very clear, it's that I have 2TB and my system is only using 1TB (os+data) and the rest is used by raid. I just want to remove raid and recover the second 1TB so I can get the 2TB.

It's very likely any given solution requires enough storage to image the disk.

"I was following a guide" - please include a link to that guide in your question

While you're editing your question, please make it clear whether you want to free up /dev/nvme0n1 or /dev/nvme1n1. The reason I'm asking is that in your first paragraph you ask, "How can I recover the second disk" but in your last block of commands you start to free up the first disk

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/190271/30851

@davolfman not necessarily. I've successfully removed RAID from a pair of disks in situ. The nice thing is that if you split the mirror off first you have a ready-made backup in the event that it all goes pear-shaped
